# UIVIew animation under the UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I would like to achieve this kind of simple animation effect:

[image]

So there are those two Labels (Label: and the 29.8 which is in the ViewController as a `@IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!`) and UIView under those two (`@IBOutlet weak var pm10View: UIView!`)
Unfortunately the CGAffineTransform doesn't work because it resizes this rectangle as an anchor point was in the center. I've tried setting the anchor point to the top-left corner but then the UIView was misplace:

```
pm10View.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) { 

    self.pm10View.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.2, y: 1.0)
}
```

So how to keep this UIView in the same position as in the Main.storyboard (anchor the top-left and bottom-left corner) and resize only Y value. While the UIView is under the UILabel does it require to be in Stack View or something to keep everyithing in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, your question is unclear? do you want to increase the width of the label?
if so,

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) { 
    yourLabel.frame.size.width = newWidthValue;
    yourLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```